# How can we convert a Signal-to-noise in decible?

Tags: database

suppose ,
we get a value of Signal-to-noise(SNR) is 255.
what is value of SNR in dB ?

Note:
we know, 
if a value is given 30 dB.
the SNR value will be = 10^3 = 1000

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is not meant for this type of question, it's for programming. You better ask on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to physics sciences.

Answer (score 0):

**SNR Calculation – Simple**

If your signal and noise measurements are already in dB form, simply subtract the noise figure from the main signal: S - N. Because when you subtract logarithms, it is the same as dividing normal numbers. The difference of the numbers is the SNR. For example: you measure a radio signal with a strength of -5 dB and a noise signal of -40 dB. -5 - (-40) = 35 dB.

**SNR Calculation – Complicated**

To calculate SNR, divide the value of the main signal by the value of the noise, and then take the common logarithm of the result: log(S ÷ N). There’s one more step: If your signal strength figures are units of power (watts), multiply by 20; if they are units of voltage, multiply by 10. For power, SNR = 20 log(S ÷ N); for voltage, SNR = 10 log(S ÷ N). The result of this calculation is the SNR in decibels. For example, your measured noise value (N) is 1 microvolt, and your signal (S) is 200 millivolts. The SNR is 10 log(.2 ÷ .000001) or 53 dB.

info from https://sciencing.com/how-to-calculate-signal-to-noise-ratio-13710251.html

This question might be best on https://physics.stackexchange.com/ though